# Service values still undefined after subscribing

Tags: angular, service, components

I have a function that is called once a user selects a value in a form:

```
onChange($x: any){
  this.ApiService
      .getCarsByManufacturer($x.target.value)
      .subscribe(data => this.carListAfterManufacturerSelect = data);
  console.log(this.carListAfterManufacturerSelect)
}
```

The service:

```
getCarsByManufacturer(manufacturer: string): Observable<Cars[]>{
    return this.http.get<Cars[]>(this.apiBaseUrl + '/cars/spec/' + manufacturer)
  }
```

I want to use the user's selected value as a parameter for my function but `carListAfterManufacturerSelect` keeps returning `undefined`. Any suggestions?

Comment: this is an asynchronous call. You have to move your log inside the subscribe in order to work.

Comment: Are you sure `$x.target.value` returns the true selected value?

Comment: @Random well but I'm saving it to a variable, shouldn't the value stay there? If not, how do I use the variable then?

Comment: @Moamen yes, the parameter is there and correct.

Comment: the subscribe is executed when you receive the answer from the HTTP call. So the only way to do something when the variable is set, is to do it inside the subscribe (or to call a method in the subscribe). Anything outside the subscribe is not guaranteed to be executed after the HTTP call has responded

Comment: @Random I see, but the purpose of me getting this data is so that I could use it further on in the component, is there a way to do that? To store the data I got from `getCarsByManufacturer()` and save it in a local variable in the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how subscribe works:

```
onChange($x: any){
  this.ApiService.getCarsByManufacturer($x.target.value).subscribe(data => {
    this.carListAfterManufacturerSelect = data;
    console.log('2. Received !', this.carListAfterManufacturerSelect); // filled
    this.codeToBeExecutedAfterHttpCallIsReceived()
  });
  console.log('1. Not received yet', this.carListAfterManufacturerSelect); // undefined
}

codeToBeExecutedAfterHttpCallIsReceived() {
  console.log('3. Received too !', this.carListAfterManufacturerSelect); // filled
  // do a lot of complex stuff with carListAfterManufacturerSelect
}
```